# Búsqueda de la ruta en un Laberinto C++

Tags: c++, algoritmos, matrices, random, pilas

Buen día, Ya genere la matriz 12x12, pero no se como realizar el resto. Agradeciera su ayuda!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int matriz [12][12];

    for (int fila = 0; fila < 12; fila++){
        for (int columna = 0; columna < 12; columna++){
            matriz[fila][columna] = rand() % 2;
            cout << matriz[fila][columna] << " ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

   cout << "*********************************************************" << endl;

   system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Condiciones:

1. El laberinto estará representado por una matriz de 12 X 12, donde los
   datos serán generados aleatoriamente entre el número 0 y el numero 1.

- El numero 0 representa un camino por donde se puede avanzar
- El número 1 representa un muro del laberinto.

2. La entrada al laberinto se generará aleatóriamente (E)
3. La salida será una posición en cualquier lateral de la matriz diferente de la
   entrada. (fila 0, fila 11, columna 0, columna 11).
4. Se debe usar la estructura Pila, para almacenar
   la ruta exitosa. Dato: La estructura Pila le permitirá regresar a la posición
   anterior una vez encuentre un muro.
5. Existirán cuatro desplazamientos: arriba, abajo, derecha, izquierda.

[image: Figura1. Ejemplo de Laberinto (Visualización)]

Comment: Un mapa como este es un grafo. Busca algoritmos sobre cómo recorrer grafos, y cuéntanos qué problemas te encuentras. Revisa [ask].